# Incompatible Gradle Versions - Google Play Services

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

Since I upgraded my Google Play Services library to version 16.0.0 my Linter throws the following error:

> Incompatible Gradle Versions
>
> ../../build.gradle: All
>   com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 16.0.1, 16.0.0. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0

I displayed all dependencies and saw this:

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
>
> |    |    +---
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1

Apparently google play-services-location 16.0.0 has an internal dependency to play-services-base 16.0.1 which causes the error by version mismatch.

In my projects gradle file I already updated the google dependency to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

I have to ship the app with locations-version 16.0.0, how can I fix this?

edit:
dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile libraries.support
    compile project(path: ':core')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0' {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile libraries.kotlin
    compile libraries.eventbus

    // Dagger 2 and Compiler
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    provided libraries.appcompat
    kapt libraries.daggerCompiler
```

Comment: can you add your gradle file ? the app module

Comment: voted to close this because the `dependencies` from the `build.gradle` are missing... which does not permit to reproduce the issue in a reliable manner, but only mere guessing.

Comment: uhm. there are still no version numbers. these variables could be just anything. and if you look on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location/16.0.0) ...there isn't even any `support-v4` contained. the one guessed answer does still appear likely (as a replacement for the exclusion, which you have there).

Answer (score 3):

You can try excluding 16.0.1 from the location services gradle import something like:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0') {
    exclude group:'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, but without play-services-base the project does not compile due to missing classes

Comment: Can you share the output from gradle app:dependencies
or ./gradlew app:dependencies?

Comment: @Piwo it needs to be excluded and explicitly added in the version, which it demands... else it won't be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.google.gms') {
            if (requested.name.contains("play-services-location")) {
                details.useVersion "16.0.0"
            }
            if (requested.name.contains("play-services-base")) {
                details.useVersion "16.0.0"
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

try this one